# HTML5 EventSource onmessage never called from Web API 2

Tags: c#, javascript, html, angularjs, server-sent-events

I have a RESTful Web API 2 solution whose methods are called from an AngularJS application. I wanted to add support for sending notifications from the server side API to the client logic. However the message and open methods setup via calls to addEventListener in the Javascript are never called. The Web API controller is as follows:

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly List<StreamWriter> ConnectedClients = new List<StreamWriter>();
        private static Timer _timer;

        public EventController()
        {
            if(_timer == null)
                _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
        }

        public static void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent headers, TransportContext context)
        {
            var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
            ConnectedClients.Add(streamwriter);
        }

        private static void MessageCallback(Message m)
        {
            foreach (var subscriber in ConnectedClients)
            {
                try
                {
                    subscriber.Write("data: {0}\n\n", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m));
                    subscriber.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // This probably means the user has disconnected
                    ConnectedClients.Remove(subscriber);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(object state)
        {
            var m = new Message
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u"),
                Text = "Hello World!"
            };
            MessageCallback(m);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // New subscription request
            var response = request.CreateResponse();
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent((Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>)OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have also tried the following for my HttpGet method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    // New subscription request
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>)OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
    return response;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var eventSource = new EventSource(GlobalConfig.apiRoot + 'Event');

    eventSource.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
        console.log("open");
    }, false);

    eventSource.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        console.log("error");
    }, false);

    eventSource.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log('message');
    }, false);

} else {
    // not supported!
}
```

I am running this via IISExpress under Visual Studio 2013. However I have also tested under IIS 8 with the same result. All tests done in version 36.0.1985.143 m of Google Chrome. What I can verify is:

1. The Get method in the Web API is called.
2. The timer (which I setup simply for the sake of testing) runs and calls the TimerCallback method as expected. The MessageCallback is then run.
3. If I shut down Visual Studio/IISExpress with Chrome open the error method in the Javascript is called with a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.
4. Similarly if I shut down the browser with Visual Studio/IISExpress running an HttpException is thrown in the MessageCallback controller method.

That is, there does appear to be some sort of connection, but I can't figure out why the message and open handlers are never called in the Javascript.

To check that nothing in AngularJS may have been affecting things I moved my Javascript to a static HTML page. The following was logged in the Chrome console:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/.../api/Event
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/event-stream
Cache-Control:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/.../test.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
```

The status for the request is always 'pending'. However given that the connection stays open this is what I would expect.

Any suggestions with regard to getting this functional will be gratefully received.

Comment: Ok, this does run under IIS 8, but it can take up to 2 minutes for the request to return. Then all of the messages are dumped back to the client. I changed the timer so it was initialised in the HttpGet method and only ran for 3 iterations before calling the Dispose() method on the timer. The result however was similar.

Comment: Just to add that other calls to the API take between 180 and 500 (max) milliseconds. So the minute this is taking is extraordinarily long. I have also noticed that after the logic disposes of the timer the EventSource error method is always called. The readystate for the event source hasn't been set to closed though.

Comment: Hi Fhevol, any update for your issue? From my knowledge, your controller constructor should be mark as static or IIS will create new instance of controller per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct formatting is:

```
subscriber.Write("event: message\n");
subscriber.Write("data: {0}\n\n");
```

The event listener only responds to events that contain the event message name (in this case `message`). This means the server is able to send multiple event types that can be subscribed to separately.